# Problem solving by using Graph Theory

Tags: graph-theory

In a group of 9 people, is it possible for every one to know exactly 3 other people in the group?

I just learnt a theorem that in any graph G, the number of odd vertices in G is even.

Does it related to the question stated?

Comment: Imagine drawing the "know" graph. (We assume knowing is symmetric.) Each vertex has degree $3$.

Comment: What do you mean by number of "odd" vertices and also this depends on if the graph you are talking about is directed or not i.e. if I "know" you does it mean you "know" me?

Comment: The relevant theorem here is that the number of vertices with odd degree in a graph is even. This follows from $\sum_v \deg v=2E$. Reduction modulo $2$ kills the vertices with even degree, those with odd degree contribute $1$ to the sum, so $n=0\mod 2$ where $n$ is the number of vertices of odd degree.

Comment: thanks you all for giving me the idea, as I study independently so need some effort to understand it. I understood the relation between the question and the theorem already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Represent each person by a vertex and if two people know each other, connect them with an edge. If everyone knows exactly $3$ other people in the group, every vertex has degree $3$. Now, you can use your theorem to see why it is impossible.